# Passing pColumns with space as params in ExecuteSqlRaw

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to execute a stored procedure using `ExecuteSqlRaw`. Normal params are getting executed properly, but when I tried to execute a stored procedure with the mandatory parameter like below

```
List<SqlParameter> Params = new List<SqlParameter>
    {
        new SqlParameter("ContactEMail", "test@gmail.in"),
        new SqlParameter("Name", "test" ),
        new SqlParameter("Password", "test"),
    };
SqlParameter[] parameters1 = Params.ToArray();
var res = cn.ExecuteSqlRaw("Tool_CreateCustomer  @ContactEMail, @Name, @Password", parameters1);
```

and the database column is like:

[image]

I am getting this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'CreateCustomer' expects parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.

[image]

Executing in SQL works
[image]

Comment: The "updated" code is still invalid. Post the *actual* code that produces this error

Comment: I Am going to guess that parameters1 is your list of SqlParameter called Params.

var res = cn.ExecuteSqlRaw("Tool_CreateCustomer, parameters1);

Comment: Sorry that typo . Have updated the code now

Comment: Sorry that was my clients SP and it was encrypted ! :| I have asked for the decryption key once got it shall share the definition here

Comment: Please check have uploaded the definition

Comment: Should all the params need to be passed from the definition?

Comment: Have you tried my previous comment?

Comment: @t00n Yes tried it throws "{"Procedure or function 'Tool_CreateCustomer' expects parameter '@ContactEMail', which was not supplied."}" when tried passing the parameter list directly 
 var res = cn.ExecuteSqlRaw("Tool_CreateCustomer", parameters1);

Answer (score 2):

You are only passing 3 out of 5 parameters AND you are not using the correct method to handle optional parameters. If you only wish to pass 3 parameters (and your stored procedure parameters are defined with defaults) then change your code from:

```
Tool_CreateCustomer @ContactEMail, @Name, @Password;
```

to the following where you explicitly tell SQL Server which parameters you are providing

```
Tool_CreateCustomer @ContactEMail = @ContactEMail, @Name = @Name, @Password = @Password;
```

You might think that SQL Server can deduce which parameter is which in your code, but actually when you leave out the assignment it just matches them up in ordinal order. You can name your parameters anything you like in both examples, in the first example they are mapped by order, and in the second you map them.

[Official Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/execute-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Column name ContactEMail has space ( Contact E Mail  ) in column should we need to add space while passing params too ?

Comment: @Dah How are column names relevant when calling an SP? Parameter names have no relationship with column names. Your signature shows no spaces, so there should be no need for spaces. But even better - just try it :)

Comment: @DahSra - how did you get on?

Comment: No. Sorry am being too naive here .  Now this approach doesn't throw me any errors after passing all the param but the return value is -1 :(